# Finding specific words and add them into a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to find the words that start with "CHAPTER" and add them to a dictionary.

I have written some but It gives me 0 as an output all the time:

```
def wordcount(filename, listwords):

    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        read = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        for word in listwords:
            lower = word.lower()
            count = 0
            for sentence in read:
                line = sentence.split()
                for each in line:
                    line2=each.lower()  
                    line2=line2.strip("")
                    if lower == line2:
                        count += 1
            print(lower, ":", count)
    except FileExistError:
        print("The file is not there ")

wordcount("dad.txt", ["CHAPTER"])
```

the txt file is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XMj28QzvDx/)

EDİT*

The problem was encoding type and I solved it but the new question is that How can I add these words into a dictionary?
and How can I make this code case sensitive I mean when I type `wordcount("dad.txt", ["CHAPTER"])` I want it to find only CHAPTER words with upper case.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your `dad.txt` file ?

Comment: I added it to my main thread

Comment: Your code worked for me. Most likely your file is empty. Can you print len(read) in your code and try again.

Comment: I don't know how but my file was empty when I checked it after your message, and I fixed it but now I'm getting an encoding error How can I make this code open the file with "UTF-8"?

Comment: open() has encoding option. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @YemlihaKıyakoğlu Do you only need the `CHAPTER _` headers or all the words that start with chapter? Including the chapter in such sentences: * more than a few
first **chapters**, and the intention*

Comment: I could run the code properly and It gave me value 55 as output but I still do not know how to add them into a dictionary, any help with it?

Comment: Take help from Deepak Gouda'a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to find chapters and paragraphs, don't try and count words or split any line

For example, start simpler. Since chapters are in numeric order, you only need a list, not a dictionary

```
chapters = [] # list of chapters  
chapter = "" # store one chapter  

with open(filename, encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # TODO: should skip to the first line that starts with "CHAPTER", otherwise 'chapters' variable gets extra, header information 

        if line.startswith("CHAPTER"):
            print("Found chapter: " + line) 
            # Save off the most recent, non empty chapter text, and reset 
            if chapter:
                chapters.append(chapter) 
                chapter = "" 
        else:
             # up to you if you want to skip empty lines 
            chapter += line  # don't manipulate any data yet 

# Capture the last chapter at the end of the file 
if chapter:
    chapters.append(chapter) 
    del chapter  # no longer needed 

# del chapters[0] if you want to remove the header information before the first chapter header 

# Done reading the file, now work with strings in your lists 
print(len(chapters))  # find how many chapters there are
```

If you actually did want the text following "CHAPTER", then you can split that line in the first if statement, however note that the chapter numbers repeat between volumes, and this solution assumes the volume header is part of a chapter

If you want to count the paragraphs, start with finding the empty lines (for example split each element on `'\n\n'`)

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you need to check if a word starts with a certain words from `listwords` rather than equality (`lower == line2`). Hence, you should use [`startswith`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith) method.
You can have a simpler code, something like this.

```py
def wordcount(filename, listwords):
    listwords = [s.lower() for s in listwords]
    wordCount = {s:0 for s in listwords} # A dict to store the counts
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            for word in line.split():
                for s in listwords:
                    if word.lower().startswith(s):
                        wordCount[s]+=1
    return wordCount
```

Comment: You'll need a function to return something.

Comment: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: @DeepakGouda I just edited line 4 to change encoding but I get none value as output, can you please help? New line 4: `with open(filename,encoding="UTF-8") as f:`

Comment: and I'm trying to run the code with this end line `wordcount("d:/Okul) BIM/dad.txt", "[CHAPTER]")`

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work because of this line:

```py
if lower == line2:
```

you can use this line to find the words that start with "CHAPTER"

```py
if line2.startswith(lower):
```

Comment: Why not? Both are words.

Comment: `==` means that the two words must be the same.  word `CHAPTER` and `CHAPTER_two` are not the same. But `CHAPTER_two` start with word `CHAPTER`.

Comment: He is converting both words to lowecase.